# use jquery to return information from a php script that's running mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I know that title a bit confusing, so I'll try to explain better here.

I'm trying to create a form where a user inputs a ticket and that ticket gets assigned to a technician based off the service they provide. I have 3 text fields, username,email, Description of the problem. The next field is a select field. I populate this select field by running a php script that will query a database of services offered and return the results. 
so something like

```
<select name="service' id= "Service" onClick="showTechnican()">
<?php include "services_offered.php"?>
</select>
```

When a user clicks on one of the services, I want the form to query my services_offered table and return the username(s) that provide that service in a div.

```
<div id="techs"></div>
```

I'm using a jquery script to do this

```
<script>
function showTechnician(){
var selectedValue = $("#Service").val();
if(selectedValue.length < 1){
    document.getElementById("techs").inner.HTML = "Please Select A Service Above";
    return;
}else{
    var url = "technicians.php?q="+selectedValue;
    $.get(url,function(data,status){
        document.getElementById("techs").innerHTML=data;
    });
}
  }
```

I've also got the script technicians.php that is querying the database for me

```
<select name= "tech">
<?php
$q = $GET['q'];
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "proxy_user",
    "my*password","helpdesk");
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo'Unable to connect to database:'.
    mysqli_connect_error($conn);
}
    else{
        $query = "SELECT * FROM services WHERE Service_Descripton LIKE'%".$q.
        "%';";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        if(!$result){
            die("Invalid Query:" . mysqli_error($conn));
        }
            else{
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                    echo"<option value= "."{$row['User_Name']}>"."{$row['Service_Description']}".
                    '</option><br/>';
                }
                mysqli_close($conn);
            }
    }
   ?>
```

my issue is that when I click on a service offered, my div only shows a small empty box. Not really sure why it's not returning anything. I've got plenty of test data in the table. Made sure permissions were correct as well.  I've checked the php_error_log and the query isn't failing. I'm not sure how to resolve this. Every other field on the form will insert just fine into the database. 
I've attached a photo of the issue. See under "available testers" it just displays a little box.

[photo of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VU0Np.png)

Comment: There is a wrong quote in `name="service'`. Maybe is this breaking your code?

Comment: @CJNimes - Pretty sure that's what's causing the problem.  They just need a double quote instead of a single quote.  It looks like there's going to be no id value for that select because it thinks it's part of a string ..."service' id= "...

Comment: I'm going to check it out after work today. Thank you both for the feedback. Will update with results.

Comment: @CJNimes that didn't work unfortunately. I'll keep working at it, thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I can't spell, had a spelling mistake in the output of my query. Fixed it and everything worked as it should.